# Make Ruby object respond to double splat operator **

Tags: ruby, double-splat

I have a library that has an `#execute` method like this

```
def execute(query, **args)
  # ...
end
```

I have a class that generates the data for `args` (which has a lot of logic depending on user abilities)

```
class Abilities
  def to_h
    { user: user } # and a lot more data
  end
end
```

Now when I'm using `#execute` I always have to remember to use `#to_h`, which is pretty annoying and leads to mistakes when someone forgets it:

```
execute(query, abilities.to_h)
```

So I was wondering if my `Abilities` class could somehow respond to the `**` (double splat) operator, so that I can simply pass the object:

```
execute(query, abilities)
```

When I try to call it like this, it throws an error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

So, is there any way to make my `Abilities` class behave like a `Hash`? I could derive it like this `Abilities < Hash` but then I have all the Hash logic on it, which seems pretty dirty.

Comment: `execute(query, **abilities)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement `to_hash`: (or define it as an alias for `to_h`)

```
class MyClass
  def to_hash
    { a: 1, b: 2 }
  end
end

def foo(**kwargs)
  p kwargs: kwargs
end

foo(MyClass.new)
#=> {:kwargs=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the API to `execute` in such a way that it accepts anything that supports `to_h`, then you have a solution:

```
def execute(query, args = {})
  args = args.to_h
  ...
end
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can't alter the definition of `#execute` because it's inside a gem, and I don't want to monkey patch it